# Problems with form validation in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In this little function I validate incoming emails using module "email-check" (it works, so no problems here) and using "count" method in my mongoDB collection. Here is the code:

```
var emailCheck = require("email-check"),
express = require("express");

var Validate = function (email, dbCollection) {
    emailCheck(email)
        .then(function (res) {
            if (res === true && dbCollection.count({"email": email}) === 0) {
                console.log("Email is OK ");
                dbCollection.insert({"email": email.toLowerCase()});
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            if (err.message === "refuse") {
                console.log("The MX server is refusing requests from your IP address");
            } else {
                console.log("Unexpected error");
            }
        });
};

module.exports = Validate;
```

But, I am sure, this fragment does not work: 
**dbCollection.count({"email": email}) === 0**

Console shows me that: "Promise ". I cannot get what is wrong here and how can I rewrite this to make everything work. Help me out with this :)

P.S: mongoDB version is 2.2, all code except for bolded one works just fine.

Comment: I don't see bolded.

Comment: The database methods are also async. Whole function needs to return a promise really.

Comment: @Lazyexpert corrected that.

Comment: @NeilLunn so how should I rewrite dbCollection.count({"email": email}) === 0 so it will behave like expected?

Comment: You need to respect the Promise/Callback. [Read the duplicate question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). You still don't seem to have a grasp of async calls and returns